# create table based on a user defined type

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

Suppose I have a user defined type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYPE AS OBJECT
( 
    f1 varchar2(10),
    f2 number(5)
);
```

Now, I want to create a table to hold these types.  I can do the following:

```
create table test_type_table (
    test_type_field test_type
);
```

This gives me a table with one column, `test_type_field`.

Is there an easy and automated way to instead create a table such that it has 2 columns, `f1` and `f2`?.  So that it's the equivilent to writing:

```
create table test_type_table (
    f1 varchar2(10),
    f2 number(5)
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
create table test_type_table of test_type;
```

Comment: @Thomas, no, I hadn't, but I really should have.  Guess I'm having a slow morning

Comment: For TSQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390358/create-sql-server-table-based-on-a-user-defined-type