# Create SQL Server user defined table type based on a table

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

I have a table in SQL Server. I want to bulk upload rows into this table using a user-defined table type ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030848/how-to-pass-user-defined-table-type-as-stored-procedured-parameter-in-c-sharp)). To do this, I need to create a user-defined table type with the same format as my destination table.

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to copy all of the column information by hand?

In other words, I'm looking for the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390358/create-sql-server-table-based-on-a-user-defined-type) (*create SQL Server table based on a user defined type*).

I want to turn this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    AAA [int] NOT NULL,
    BBB [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CCC [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

into this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtMyTable] 
AS TABLE
   (
      AAA [int] NOT NULL,
      BBB [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
      CCC [datetime] NOT NULL
   )
```

Is it safe just to do a text-replace?

Comment: Of course. Why would it be an issue?

Comment: Doing it the other way around using the method in the question I linked seems super easy.  I was wondering if there's a way to do that in reverse.

Comment: @user2023861, `SELECT...INTO` can be used to create a table but not a table type so there is no reverse in this case.  The text replace method is the easiest unless you need to do this in code.

Answer (score 1):

*Brace yourselves, a hideous CTE filled with `CONCAT` is coming...*

- [Also available as a Gist on my GitHub](https://gist.github.com/daiplusplus/4078d2f4526bde007edaf6d217abb10c#file-showcreatetypefromtables-sql), for posterity

  - The Gist contains multiple files, so scroll down to `ShowCreateTypeFromTables.sql`)
- This Table-valued `FUNCTION` below will generate a `CREATE TYPE ... AS TABLE (...)` statement for every table in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.
- Further down, is a scalar `FUNCTION` that returns a single string `CREATE TYPE` statement for the single specified table and schema.
- Example output is also shown below.
- Features:

  - *Yes!*, it's **copy-and-pasteable!**
  - Neatly left-aligns column names and type-names.
  - Includes column ordinals in comments so you can easily match them up to `SqlDataReader` and `SqlDataRecord` column ordinals.
  - Generates `PRIMARY KEY` constraints based on the source table's PK, including support for composite PKs.
  - Handles `max`-length columns.
  - Escapes all column names in square-brackets. Unfortunately T-SQL doesn't have an "escape-only-if-necessary" function, because I find excessive square-brackets hideous (looking at you, SSDT).
  - As these are all `FUNCTION` objects, not `PROCEDURE` objects, these don't require any special permissions to run, and cannot possibly make any changes to your database directly (you will need to copy+paste the generated `CREATE TYPE` statement into a new SSMS editor and run it yourself). So *nyaaaa*!, you can't sue me for nuking your production DB
- Things-not-supported:

  - Indexes on table-types are not generated.
  - Anything I haven't thought of also won't be included in the feature-set.
- Important notes:

  - Requires support for `STRING_AGG` which means you need SQL Server 2017 and your DB in Compatibility Level 140 or higher.
  - I kinda glossed-over using `CONCAT` with `nvarchar` vs. `varchar` strings - so that's a possible improvement.
  - You might want to change the schema from `dbo` to whatever schema you use for DBA tools that shouldn't be mingled with production `dbo`-schema objects.

#### Part 1: `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ShowCreateTypeFromTables()`

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ShowCreateTypeFromTables() RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN
WITH
    pkCols AS (
        SELECT
            kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            kcu.TABLE_NAME,
            CONCAT( '[', kcu.COLUMN_NAME, ']' ) AS COLUMN_NAME,
            kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION AS PK_Ordinal
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu ON
                tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                AND
                tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        WHERE
            tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    ),
    pkDefExprs AS (
        SELECT
            k.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            k.TABLE_NAME,
            CONCAT(
                CHAR(13),CHAR(10), /* CRLF \r\n */
                CHAR(13),CHAR(10), /* CRLF \r\n */
                CHAR(9), /* TAB \t */
                'PRIMARY KEY ( ',
                STRING_AGG( k.COLUMN_NAME, /*separator:*/ ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY k.PK_Ordinal ),
                ' )'
            ) AS PKDefinition 
        FROM
            pkCols AS k
        GROUP BY
            k.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            k.TABLE_NAME
    ),

    maxColNameLengths AS (
    
        SELECT
            c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            c.TABLE_NAME,
            MAX( LEN( c.COLUMN_NAME ) + 2 ) AS MaxColumnNameLength /* +2 for the [] added in `allCols` below */
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
        GROUP BY
            c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            c.TABLE_NAME
    ),

    allCols AS (
        SELECT
            c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            c.TABLE_NAME,
            c.COLUMN_NAME,
            LEFT( CONCAT( '[', c.COLUMN_NAME, ']', SPACE( ml.MaxColumnNameLength ) ), ml.MaxColumnNameLength ) AS ColumnNamePad,
            c.DATA_TYPE,
            c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
            (
                CASE
                    WHEN c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL THEN c.DATA_TYPE
                    WHEN c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN CONCAT( c.DATA_TYPE, '(max)' )
                    ELSE CONCAT( c.DATA_TYPE, '(', c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')' )
                END
            ) AS ColumnTypeExpr,
            ( CASE c.IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'YES' THEN '    NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END ) AS NullableExpr,
            c.ORDINAL_POSITION
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON
                c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                AND
                c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        
            INNER JOIN maxColNameLengths AS ml ON
                c.TABLE_SCHEMA = ml.TABLE_SCHEMA
                AND
                c.TABLE_NAME = ml.TABLE_NAME
    ),
    createTableColumnExprs AS (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
                CHAR(9), /* \t TAB */
                allCols.ColumnNamePad, ' ',
                LEFT( CONCAT( allCols.ColumnTypeExpr, SPACE(17) ), 17 ), ' ',
                allCols.NullableExpr, ' ',
                '/* ', ( allCols.ORDINAL_POSITION - 1 ), ' */'
            ) AS ColumnExpr,
            allCols.*
        FROM
            allCols
    ),
    createTableExprs AS (
        SELECT
            e.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            e.TABLE_NAME,
            STRING_AGG( e.ColumnExpr, /*separator:*/ CONCAT(',', CHAR(13), CHAR(10) ) ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY e.ORDINAL_POSITION ) AS ColumnExprs 
        FROM
            createTableColumnExprs AS e
        GROUP BY
            e.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            e.TABLE_NAME
    )

    SELECT
        ct.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        ct.TABLE_NAME,
        
        CONCAT(
            'CREATE TYPE ',
            ct.TABLE_SCHEMA,
            '.TypeOf_',
            ct.TABLE_NAME,
            ' AS TABLE (',
            CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10)),
            ct.ColumnExprs,
            ISNULL( pke.PKDefinition, '' ),
            CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10)),
            ');',
            CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10))
        ) AS CreateTypeExpr

    FROM
        createTableExprs AS ct
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pkDefExprs AS pke ON
            ct.TABLE_SCHEMA = pke.TABLE_SCHEMA
            AND
            ct.TABLE_NAME = pke.TABLE_NAME
```

#### Part 2: `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ShowCreateTypeFromTable( @schema sysname, @tableName sysname )`

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ShowCreateTypeFromTable( @schema sysname, @tableName sysname ) RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS

BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max) = NULL;
    SELECT
        @stmt = e.CreateTypeExpr
    FROM
        dbo.ShowCreateTypeFromTables() AS e
    WHERE
        e.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
        AND
        e.TABLE_NAME = @tableName;

    RETURN @stmt;
    
END
```

#### Part 3: Example usage and output:

```
USE AdventureWorks2017;

SELECT [dbo].[ShowCreateTypeFromTable] ( 'Production', 'Product'  )
GO

-- Generates this:

CREATE TYPE Production.TypeOf_Product AS TABLE (

    [ProductID]             int               NOT NULL /* 1 */,
    [Name]                  nvarchar(50)      NOT NULL /* 2 */,
    [ProductNumber]         nvarchar(25)      NOT NULL /* 3 */,
    [MakeFlag]              bit               NOT NULL /* 4 */,
    [FinishedGoodsFlag]     bit               NOT NULL /* 5 */,
    [Color]                 nvarchar(15)          NULL /* 6 */,
    [SafetyStockLevel]      smallint          NOT NULL /* 7 */,
    [ReorderPoint]          smallint          NOT NULL /* 8 */,
    [StandardCost]          money             NOT NULL /* 9 */,
    [ListPrice]             money             NOT NULL /* 10 */,
    [Size]                  nvarchar(5)           NULL /* 11 */,
    [SizeUnitMeasureCode]   nchar(3)              NULL /* 12 */,
    [WeightUnitMeasureCode] nchar(3)              NULL /* 13 */,
    [Weight]                decimal               NULL /* 14 */,
    [DaysToManufacture]     int               NOT NULL /* 15 */,
    [ProductLine]           nchar(2)              NULL /* 16 */,
    [Class]                 nchar(2)              NULL /* 17 */,
    [Style]                 nchar(2)              NULL /* 18 */,
    [ProductSubcategoryID]  int                   NULL /* 19 */,
    [ProductModelID]        int                   NULL /* 20 */,
    [SellStartDate]         datetime          NOT NULL /* 21 */,
    [SellEndDate]           datetime              NULL /* 22 */,
    [DiscontinuedDate]      datetime              NULL /* 23 */,
    [rowguid]               uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL /* 24 */,
    [ModifiedDate]          datetime          NOT NULL /* 25 */
    
    PRIMARY KEY ( [ProductID] )
);
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]