# Can I construct a table with the user-defined table type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I have a table type named EmpType with the following structure:

```
CREATE TYPE EmpType AS TABLE
(
ClientId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
EmployeeId INT,
Experience SMALLINT,
Age SMALLINT
);
```

This query ran successfully in the MS SQL Server.

Now that I try to construct another table using this table type it gives me an error.

```
CREATE TABLE EmpHashIndex2
(
HashIndex SMALLINT CONSTRAINT has_pk PRIMARY KEY,
TableName dbo.EmpType
);
```

After executing the above query it gives an error as:

```
The column "TableName" does not have a valid data type. A column cannot be of a user-defined table type.
```

Comment: If you want a column of that type, then whats is unclear in the message "A column cannot be of a user-defined table type."? It's a resounding no, isn't it? If you want a table of that type however see ["create SQL Server table based on a user defined type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390358/create-sql-server-table-based-on-a-user-defined-type).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to store multiple rows in a single row. That's not how a DBMS works. you need to create 2 tables, and define your primary and foreign key so that you have a define many to one relationship.

Comment: @Samarth please describe the task you're struggling with. What are you trying to achieve with such a model?

Comment: Of course not!!! A table cannot have a table as a column. That is like asking if you can put an entire excel tab in a single cell. It makes no sense.

Comment: I just want to each cell of the 'TableName' column to point to a different table which I can utilize elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to apply OOP approaches to Relational DB. Something like "pointer"s to *any* data. That is not how it works in RDBMS.

Perhaps you need a relational schema like this:

`Client <- EmployeePerClient -> Employee`

None of them has to be a `table type`, all of them must be `table`s with `foreign key`s defining their dependencies.